# SQL Variable date minus a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, dateadd

I have a stored proc which has a user input of a date (YYYMMDD).

To build the final part of the query I need to get the date that has been input to the date 12 months ago.

I have tried a few different methods such as casting it as datetime or dateadd functions but still no luck: below is a snipit of my code:

```
@DateSelected datetime=null,
@year int=null,
@week int=null,
@DayOfWeek int=null,
@DateSelectedLastYear datetime=null
--@Day int=null
as
begin
    --if date parms are null get current week and year
    if (@DateSelected is null)
        begin
            select @Year=year_number,@Week=week_number,@DayOfWeek=day_of_week from infrastructure..calendar
            where calendar_date=DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1))
        end
    else
    begin
        select @Year=year_number,@Week=week_number,@DayOfWeek=day_of_week from infrastructure..calendar
        where calendar_date=@DateSelected
    end
    begin
    Select
         @DateSelectedLastYear = DATEADD(YYYY,-1,@DateSelected)
    end
```

Comment: This bit is not clear *"I need to get the date that has been input to the date 12 months ago"* can you explain?

Comment: why are you using weeks and dayofweeks? where is the user-input, which is supposed to be YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Sorry that's my fault for not paying attention when typing, @DateSelected is the input the user makes (e.g. exec sp..... '20131117'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@DateSelected datetime=null,
@year int=null,
@week int=null,
@DayOfWeek int=null,
@DateSelectedLastYear datetime=null
--@Day int=null
as
begin
    --if date parms are null get current week and year
    if (@DateSelected is null)
        begin
            select @Year=year_number,@Week=week_number,@DayOfWeek=day_of_week from     infrastructure..calendar
            where calendar_date=DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1))
        end
    else
    begin
        select @Year=year_number,@Week=week_number,@DayOfWeek=day_of_week from     infrastructure..calendar
        where calendar_date=@DateSelected
    end
    begin
    Select
        @DateSelectedLastYear = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@DateSelected)
   end
```

Comment: thanks for the help, found the issue further on in the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
select dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
```

Comment: I need a year previous from the value that gets input by the user not the date the query is run

Comment: So then put the date that gets input by the user in place of getdate().

Comment: Is your question about how to cast your input date from a string "YYYYMMDD" to a date?  I had assumed by your question that you had already figured that part out.  That's why I was thinking you could just insert your date value in place of getdate() in my code sample.

Comment: No I've got that part, it was further on the proc that it was falling over, thanks for the help